# How to continue after emerging dev-php/pecl-imagick

Tags: php, imagick, gentoo

I have successfully emerged dev-php/pecl-imagick-3.4.3,
but when i want to run a test script using imagick calls, i get an error:

```
$ php testimagick.php
Caught exception: Imagick extension is not loaded.
```

How do i load the Imagick extension?

I seem to have 2 versions of php: dev-lang/php-5.6.29 and dev-lang/php-7.0.21

My imageMagick version is 6.9.9.0

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Ebuild for `dev-php/pecl-imagick` can install and enable extension for all installed versions (slots) of dev-php.

In your case with php versions 5.6 and 7.0 to make it work you need to add `PHP_TARGETS="php5-6 php7-0"` to your `/etc/portage/make.conf` and run `emerge dev-php/pecl-imagick`.